# Stopping audio file on button click

Tags: angular, typescript

Upon clicking a button in a component I would like to stop the execution of the current playing audio file, which is played by a service. Also it should start the execution of a different audio file.

However I am having difficulty communicating with the service as well as stopping the first audio while allowing the play of the second.

word.component.ts

```
//This starts the original audio file
ngOnInit() {
   this.playWord(this.startingWord);
}

playWord(word: string) {
    this.sfx.playWordContext(word);
}
```

audio.service.ts

```
playWordContext(word: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const w = this.audioFiles[word];
    if (w != null) {
      return this.play(w);
    } else {
      console.error(`Word is null.`);
      return Observable.of(false);
    } 
    return Observable.of(false);
}

play(element: HTMLAudioElement): Observable<boolean> {
    if (element) {
      let result = true;
      const played = Observable.fromEvent(element, 'ended');
      const promise = element.play();

      if (promise) {
        promise.catch(() => {
          console.error('HTMLAudioElement cannot be played.');
          result = false;
        });
      }

      return played.map(() => (result)).take(1);
    } else {
      console.error('HTMLAudioElement is null and cannot be played.');
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
}
```

key.component.ts

```
  //When this is fired it needs to stop execution of first audio file while still playing the second
  emitKey(letter: string) {
    if (this.isNotMuted()) {
      this.sfx.play(this.sfx.letters); //this.sfx is the audio service
    }
    this.keyPressed.emit(qke);
  }
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You know you dont need to return observables for everything.

Comment: the audio service has many uses and some of them require the use of observables